# My edittext isn't editable after I use setText()

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
getTextForEdit(); //gives the values into sb
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edii);
et.setText(sb);
```

My problem is that when I run this code, the text in the edittext is not editable anymore. The only thing it allows me to do is select the text. I want to be able to edit this text.

*sb and et are globally declared. I mentioned them as declared again to avoid any confusions about their object types.*

XML code for this editText:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edii"
    android:layout_width="387dp"
    android:layout_height="296dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:maxLines="16"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-3dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.496" />
```

-thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to post your xml

Comment: and the full class code as well, I think there's something more that disable the edit text

Comment: Don't you have a typo here: `R.id.edii`?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado no its not.

Comment: @ElliotM here u go..

Comment: Are you sure you don't have android:editable="false" in your XML?

Comment: Your `editText` id is `me`, not `edii`

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Sorry, I'm not allowed to. The rest of the code is just that function using sb.append(extractedText)

Comment: @JohnJoe sorry, corrected

Comment: you say `sb` and `et` are globally declared but inside that function you declare `et` again.

Comment: @CristianGomez i tried that, but that has been deprecated.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti i did that just so it doesn't confuse people about their types. So sb is StringBuilder and et is EditText

Comment: Without the rest of the code we cannot notice what you're doing wrong. with this little code I get no errors.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti there are no errors, its just the editText thats not allowing the edits from user. :(

Comment: If you don't start using meaningful names in your variables you will have major headaches when you really start developing

Comment: can you show `getTextForEdit();` ?

Comment: @AdityaNigam what I meant is that I can edit EditTexts after settings text with the same line you use. What's the result type of `getTextForEdit()`?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti (sorry it took long) getTextForEdit() is a void function that appends text to sb.

Comment: Again, there are no error in code, and the code you're allowing us to see does not reproduce the problem. So there might be something else

Answer (score 0):

Change your EditText id edii to me (XML EditText id name is me)

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.me)
et.setText("Hello ..", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: still not working for me even after I changed it to EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE